# Displaying a list of parent items filtered by the presence of certain child items

Tags: 2013, list

Imagine the situation. There are two lists:

Projects

- Project ID
- Title
- Description

Tasks

- Task ID
- Project (lookup field, linked to the Projects list)
- Title
- Assigned (People picker field)
- Description

How can we show the list of projects that have tasks assigned to the current user. Is it possible to do this without creating custom WebPart and programming? May be via a specific CAML-Query?

Answer (score 0):

I would configure the lookup column in the Task list to pull over the Title field and Description if possible.

Then I would create a view group by project, with any applicable fields you want, filtered by Assigned is equal to [Me].

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Unfortunately, this is not an option in our case because It does not allow to implement more complex scenarios. For example, it is not possible to display only those projects that meet certain filtering conditions (for example, on the status of the project). And not all types of fields can be used as the projected fields.
So we need a solution that displays a list of projects exactly, but filtering on the basis of a subsidiary task list.